# iOS: choosing filenames when storing persistent data on iTunes library items

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence

I want to store some information on items grabbed from the iTunes library, and wondering what´s the best way to name the files without creating any problems like overwrites or similar names etc... In the Media Items that I grab from the library there are metadata, and this will probably be the best to use for names. If I use the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID I am sure there won´t be any similar names, but the value is nit guaranteed to persist during sync/unsync/sync cycle... is there a better way of doing it?

```
MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
The title (or name) of the media item. This property is unrelated to the MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle property. Value is an NSString object.

MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID
The persistent identifier for the media item. Value is an NSNumber object containing a uint64_t (unsigned long long).
The value of the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID identifier persists across application launches and across syncs that do not change the sync status of the media item. The value is not guaranteed to persist across a sync/unsync/sync cycle.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for how I create unique names for when I save images, this will give you a unique filename.

```
- (void) writeImageFile:(NSData *) image
{
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate (kCFAllocatorDefault);
    CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString (kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);
    NSString *filePath = [self getUniqueFilePathFrom:newUniqueIDString];
    [image writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    self.pathToFullSizeImage = filePath;
    CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
    CFRelease(newUniqueID);
}
```

Hope it helps you.